# Online Python interpreter for use *from* the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, python

Is there an online Python interpreter or some such that would allow me to try out simple python code from my iPhone?

Something like [try ruby! (in your browser)](http://tryruby.hobix.com/) for Python, and works with the iPhone?

Comment: Boat programming http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. Python and all interpretation is strictly verboten on the iPhone.

That said, if you jailbreak your phone, you can install linux with python and go to town.

**Edit:** I didn't notice the word "online" before. Here's an online python interpreter:

http://try-python.mired.org/

Comment: I think he is asking for a webpage in which he can paste some Python code to run it.

Comment: this is an outdated answer. There is a native python interpreter available for IOS now: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pypad/id428928902?mt=8

Comment: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ipython/id485729872?ls=1&mt=8

Comment: @chown That's... ok either Apple is slacking, or they've changed their terms.

Comment: @Randolpho: I think they said that it's okay as long as the application has no synchronization features. I don't know if they revised the restriction or if it's been like that all along.

Answer (score 8):

[CodePad](http://www.codepad.org) allows you to run snippets of Python code (and many other languages!).

Answer (score 3):

If you jailbreak the phone and install cydia, cydia can install python, including a sample python app integrating the iphone objectivec api.

Comment: I tried this myself and found it to be both very arcane (as a Python programmer who doesn't know any ObjC) and a little on the slow side.  Very promising, though.

Comment: PyObjC, that is.  The command-line Python interpreter is exactly what you'd expect.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

The Sage notebook (http://sagenb.org) can be set to Python mode, and it allows you to run arbitrary Python code over the web.  It has an evaluate button that I specifically added so I could use it from my iPhone/iPad.  I'm currently working on more support (e.g., tab completion like with iPython for the iPhone).

Answer (score 1):

I tried [Rex Tester](http://rextester.com/runcode) yesterday for the first time yesterday, it was free, excellent and without constraints on at least the system calls I needed, which is a big plus, I can really recommend it!

Answer (score 0):

Also worth noting that [This javascript-free one](http://www.datamech.com/devan/trypython/trypython.py) works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try http://live.codenode.org, which I've seen been used with an IPhone.

Answer (score 0):

There is a CodeToGo IApp built upon [IdeoneAPI](http://ideone.com)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried these specifically for iPhone but there are a lot of options for online python interpreters:

- http://www.codepad.org
- http://www.ideone.com
- http://people.csail.mit.edu/pgbovine/python/tutor.html#mode=edit
- http://portablepython.com/
- http://www.pythonanywhere.com/
- http://repl.it/
- http://www.learnpython.org/
- http://labs.codecademy.com/
- http://www.sourcelair.com/
- http://pythonfiddle.com/